# How would I turn Int 623527832412487691 to Str 623527832412487691 in JavaScript

Tags: type-conversion, numbers, large-data, largenumber

Im trying to save 623527832412487691 to my MySQL database for use in the future, the MySQL type of data is a string

```
userid STRING NOT NULL,
```

However when I retrieve the data it outputs 623527832412487700 as a Number

I have tried

```
`${623527832412487691}`
```

but that outputs `623527832412487700` as a `String`

I have also tried

```
console.log(BigInt(623527832412487691))
```

but that outputs `623527832412487680n` as a `BigInt`

Comment: Use `623527832412487691n`. Do not start with a number literal - there is no such number in float64 representation!

Comment: I understand that, however, the ID is originally a string https://imgur.com/7sLGzrx but when I print it it converts to an integer https://imgur.com/uxNmrVH and when I try to retrieve it from my database it returns as https://imgur.com/G8qmMD2

Comment: Printing does not convert anything to an integer, it just outputs the string contents. But if your database has a `string` column and you are storing string values to it, then you should also be able to retrieve string values from it, with nothing attempting a conversion anywhere. Please post all the code that interacts with the database, and debug where exactly that conversion is happening. Is the data in the database correct? What happens if you store non-numeric data?

Comment: Here is me adding to the database https://imgur.com/deSYgK2, this is the table https://imgur.com/K1TRg4P and this is the retrieved data https://imgur.com/A4IS9kl

Comment: Why are you doing `String(interaction.user.id)` if you say that `interaction.user.id` already is a string? But really, please try `"abc"` as the id.

Comment: Also please [do not post links to paintings of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572) - instead [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: interaction.user.id is a value in an array, in that array the value is a string but all numbers, no letters, so it automatically converts to a number, I tried "abc" and it stays "abc" all the way

Comment: Which mysql library are you using? That shouldn't happen.

Comment: im using the package `better-sqlite3` its a npm package

Comment: Uh, don't? That's a library for an sqlite3 database, not for mysql.

Comment: I am running the files on a Virtual Private Server, would I still be able to use the MySQL package on that? @Bergi

Comment: Sure, why not? Where is your mysql database running, on the same server? Tbh I'm more surprised that you got any output at all from using sqlite on a mysql server.

Comment: Right now the code is

```const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: ""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});```

and when i run it i receive the error code:

```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306```

How do i allow access to port 3306? on vps